# Change the owner of a file from a user to root using sudoers in linux

Tags: python, linux, django, sudoers

I want to use /etc/sudoers to change the owner of a file from bangtest(user) to root.

Reason to change: when I uploaded an image from bangtest(user) to my server using Django application then image file permission are like

```
ls -l /home/bangtest/alpha/media/products/image_2093.jpg 
-rw-r--r-- 1 bangtest bangtest 28984 May  6 02:47
```

but when I tried to access those file from server using //myhost/media/products/image_2093.jpg, I am getting 404 error.When I tried to log the error its like

```
 Caught race condition abuser. attacker: 0, victim: 502 open file owner: 502, open file: /home/bangtest/alpha/media/products/image_2093.jpg
```

After when I changed the owner of a file from bangtest to root,then I am able to access the image perfectly. 
So because of that reason I want to change owner of file dynamically using python script.

I have tried by changing the sudoers file like mentioned below.But still I am getting error like

```
chown: changing ownership of `image.jpg': Operation not permitted
```

My sudoers code:

```
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
bangtest  ALL=(ALL) /bin/chown root:bangtest /home/bangtest/alpha/*
```

Any Clues why sudoers are not working?

Note:Operating system Linux.

Thanks

Comment: And Django runs as which user?

Comment: @J0HN Django user bangtest

Comment: Are you sure you close the file when you save it? And one more thing, is cPanel involved somehow? There are lots of search hits on google for "Caught race condition abuser" that relates to cPanel.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your problem is that you're trying to access a file as a file on your local machine by using //myhost (a path to it).  // won't work with a server, if that's what you're going for, or at least it won't with the ruby on rails ones i'm using.  if it's a location on your local machine use //myhost/media/products/image_2093.jpg and if it's something you're trying to access through your server, try /myhost/media/products/image_2093.jpg.  I don't know of any good posts to refer you to but I just tested it out for myself.
Hope it helps

I was able to find some interesting info that sounds like evidence.
http://www.mail-archive.com/dev@httpd.apache.org/msg55666.html

Comment: Sorry, I'm accessing using my host http://120.0.0.1/media/products/image_2093.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Use [ACL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list)

```
setfacl -dm u::rwx,g::rwx,o::rwx /home/bangtest/alpha/media/products/
```

All files created in this folder have permissions set to rwx for all users.

EDIT:// Change permissions for chmod is dangerous, but is possible, edit /etc/sudoers

```
bangtest  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/chmod
```

Comment: ,Thanks for your reply,But when tried to run setfacl command.-bash: setfacl: command not found I got this error